Typescript ReturnType of function that returns Promise
I'm struggling with something I'm certain should be simple in Typescript. I'm trying to define a helper function that runs some function and logs a custom message if it errors (this is a simplification of the actual functionality, but it suffices for the example).
async function logIt<T extends () => Promise<any>>(message: string, fn: T): ReturnType<T> {
  try {
    const result = await fn();
    return result;
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(message);
    throw e;
  }
}

I then use it:
class Thing extends Whatever {
  // as the name suggests, this function is overwritten from `Whatever` - it's returnType is `Promise<number>`
  functionOnWhatever() {
    return logIt("hello", () => super.functionOnWhatever());
  }
}

The problem is, the logIt function complains that ReturnType<T> should be Promise<ReturnType<T>> - and when I make that change, functionOnWhatever complains that 'Promise<Promise<number>>' is not assignable to 'Promise<number>'.

• Please [edit] to provide Whatever or enough of it so that this is a [mre] we can just look at in our IDEs instead of having to parse "as the name suggests" etc and try to imagine what would happen if that were actual code. • TS has a syntactic requirement to mark async return types with Promise. Instead of Promise<ReturnType you should write Promise<Awaited<ReturnType probably... although without a [mre] I'm just guessing.

I made a guess, does this playground link meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Interesting - I've not seen Awaited before. That does indeed do it, as simple as I expected (though not obvious, in fairness). Thanks!

Note that in general you don't want to mess around with generic conditional types like ReturnType<T> for generic T. TypeScript can't really analyze such types properly. The recommended approach to a function like logIt() is to write it like this:
async function logIt<T>(message: string, fn: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {⋯}

which sidesteps your whole problem.  But if you need to use ReturnType then keep reading:

The problem you're having is that ReturnType<T> is only known to be assignable to Promise<any>, but TypeScript has a strong requirement that an async function can only be claimed to return Promise and not some possible subtype of Promise.  See microsoft/TypeScript#35191.
That's because async functions always wrap results in a new Promise; even if the function returns something assignable to Promise, it will not simply be passed through unchanged.
If logit() were allowed to return ReturnType<T> where T is the type of fn, then something like the following could happen:
async function logIt<T extends () => Promise<any>>(
  message: string, fn: T): ReturnType<T> {⋯}

const myPromise = Object.assign(Promise.resolve(1), { prop: "abc" });
//    ^? const myPromise: Promise<number> & { prop: string; }
console.log(myPromise.prop.toUpperCase()); // ABC

const newPromise = logIt("myPromise", () => myPromise);
//    ^? const newPromise: Promise<number> & { prop: string; }
console.log(newPromise.prop.toUpperCase()); //  RUNTIME ERROR!

The type of myPromise is Promise<number> with an extra property and therefore so is newPromise. But it's not, really. That extra property is gone at runtime.

So you definitely need to return Promise<⋯> instead of ReturnType<T>.  But Promise<ReturnType<T>> isn't right, since ReturnType<T> is already assignable to Promise.
What you need to say is that it's Promise<X> where X is the type you get when you await ReturnType<T>.  And for that, you can use the Awaited<T> utility type:
async function logIt<T extends () => Promise<any>>(
  message: string, fn: T
): Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<T>>> {
  try {
    const result = await fn();
    return result;
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(message);
    throw e;
  }
}

That works. Awaited<ReturnType<T>> will unwrap any Promise wrapper for T, and then you wrap it in Promise yourself with Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<T>>>.  If ReturnType<T> is Promise<number>, then Awaited<ReturnType<T>> is number, and Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<T>>> is Promise<number> again.  If, on the other hand, ReturnType<T> is Promise<number> & {prop: string}, then Awaited<ReturnType<T>> is number, and Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<T>>> is Promise<number> again. The {prop: string} disappears, just like what happens at runtime.
Playground link to code

Thanks for pointing out the Promise<T> piece too - that is indeed much cleaner!
